# Slack conversations.list method does not list all the channels

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a slack application and I have authenticated using this application. When I list all the channels, some of the private channels are not listed. Do we need the access token of workspace admin to list all the private and public channels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how Slack's security architecture works, which explains why you don't get all private channels with `conversations.list`.

A user only can only see private channel he is a member of. That includes users with admins and owner role, so even the creator of a workspace does not see private channels he is not invited to.

There are two types of tokens:

- **User token** inherit the access rights from the user who installs the
  Slack app. So if you installed a Slack app it can only see the
  private channels that you are a member of.
- Its a bit different with **bot token**. With a bot token the app can
  only see private channel the bot user is a member of.

There are two workarounds to get access to all channels:

### Generic user

Ensure a the generic user (e.g. `slackadmin`) is a member of all private channels. Then using his access token a Slack app also has access to all those private channels. This is an organizational solution.

### Collect all user tokens

Collect the tokens of all users on your workspace and then use those tokens to access all conversations incl. private channels their are a member of.
This can be achieved by asking every user to install your Slack app once (via standard OAuth "[Add to Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button)" process), which is called a configuration in Slack terms.

Answer (score 12):

Stumbled across this question when Googling for a similar issue in a large org - I was getting the public channels, but not all of them were showing.

Turns out Slack has a default limit of returning *100 channels*. To bypass this, simply pass a `limit: 9999` parameter, eg:

```
  app.client.conversations.list({
    token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
    limit: 9999
  }).then((res: any) => {...})
```

See also: [conversations.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list) API

Comment: The Slack API for limit is super confusing. The limit includes archived channels. So if you for instance do a `limit: 50` with `exclude_archived: 1` you won't necessarily get 50 channels back, in my case I was getting 16

Comment: Plus, private channels (or groups) are included AFTER the public channels, so if you have more than 50 public channels (archived or not), you will never see any groups/private channels even if you request them.

Comment: For reference, here's a link to the Slack Web API docs on rate limiting: https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/web-api#rate-limits

Answer (score 5):

```
response = client.conversations_list(types="public_channel, private_channel")
```

See https://slack.dev/python-slackclient/conversations.html